# Pictures are not shown on Mac

Tags: macos, ios, photos.app, image-capture

I can connect the iPhone to my Mac via USB. The photos.app opens but my pictures are not displayed and I cannot download them.

Is there a way to fix this? I already reset the permissions but this did not have any effect.

Comment: Have you tried image capture? It's an app that's preinstalled and is very good at extracting photos from your iPhone.

Comment: Yes, it is "Digitale Bilder" in German. I see the phone but it says "0 objects".

Comment: There are photos on the iPhone, I assume :-) Which version of iOS, which version of macOS are you running? Can you sync other stuff with iTunes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reboot helped. Sorry for asking ...

Comment: Happens to the best of us... Nice weekend!